# ViewModel to display partial information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I'm new to the ASP.NET MVC and before writing some code I'm reading a lot of forums in order to learn    patterns that are considered to be good practices. And one that caught my attention is the ViewModel. I understand that this is extremely helpful when we want to pass let's say information about two classes. A good way to do that is to create a class used only to render its information in the view having properties from both classes. But if instead of wanting to display information from two or more domain classes, I want to display partial information from a single class? For instance for a login view the user's email is not necessary at all.

So in this case does it make sense having a class User with all the properties and then multiple ViewModels containing only partial data from User or is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense:

If your class has a lot of properties and you only need to display a couple, I'd recommend to only query the fields that you need and creating a ViewModel with those properties; this will even increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel should contain all the data necessary for your view. It may contain more than that data, but not less. If your view displays only user's email, it makes sense for the viewmodel to serve only that email.